# Updated from lollipop to marshmallow causing problems

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, 6.0-marshmallow, rom-update, samsung-galaxy-a5

I got an update this morning for my Galaxy A5 (2015), to update from. Lollipop 5.0.2 to marshmallow 6.0.1 and now I keep getting this pop-up every 5 seconds.

[image: pop-up]
<sup>Screenshot (click to enlarge)</sup>

I can still receive text messages but I can't go into network settings for my SIM card. How do I fix this?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Boot in recovery (Volume Up + Power button) and clear cache. If I doesn't help, restore the factory settings.

Comment: Wiped cache from recovery mode, but it didn't work. Had to restore factory settings. Thanks.